# PS Perm Gen && Perm Gen JVM PROPERTIES?

Tags: tomcat, jvm

I need some information:

I have 2 redhat 6.1 Linux server with TOMCAT 7.0.28 and JAVA jdk1.7.0_05

On 192.168.1.20(TOM04) i have 1 instance TOMCAT 7 with the MBEAN "java.lang:type=MemoryPool,name=Perm Gen"

On 192.168.1.21(TOM01) i have 1 instance TOMCAT 7 with MBEAN "java.lang:type=MemoryPool,name=PS Perm Gen"

Why the MBEAN is not the same like "PERM GEN && PS PERM GEN" what does it mean? ( i want PS Perm Gen everywhere )

http://img27.imageshack.us/img27/5803/tom01u.png

http://img839.imageshack.us/img839/7539/tom04.png

Java version is the same: java -version java version "1.7.0_05" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_05-b06)

setnenv.sh 192.168.1.20(TOM04):

> ## !/bin/bash
>
> > LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$CATALINA_HOME/lib
> >     export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
> >
> > export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/default
> >
> > JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Xmx1024m -Xms512m -Xmn384m -server -XX:MaxPermSize=384m"
> >     JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -DLOG_ROOT_PATH=/opt/applogs/INSTANCE01"
> >     JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dcom.ogige.environment=PRODUCTION"
> >     JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError"
> >     JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -XX:HeapDumpPath=/opt/applogs"
> >     JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -XX:ParallelGCThreads=2"
> >     JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -XX:SurvivorRatio=8"
> >
> > export JAVA_OPTS=$JAVA_OPTS

setenv.sh 192.168.1.21(TOM01):

> ## !/bin/bash
>
> > LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$CATALINA_HOME/lib
> >     export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
> >
> > export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/default
> >
> > JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Xmx1024m -Xms512m -Xmn384m -server -XX:MaxPermSize=384m"
> >     JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -DLOG_ROOT_PATH=/opt/applogs/INSTANCE01"
> >     JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dcom.Ogige.environment=PRODUCTION"
> >     JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError"
> >     JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -XX:HeapDumpPath=/opt/applogs"
> >     JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -XX:ParallelGCThreads=2"
> >     JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -XX:SurvivorRatio=8"
> >
> > export JAVA_OPTS=$JAVA_OPTS

Comment: I have "migrate" my TOMCAT instance FROM: 192.168.1.20(TOM04) TO 192.168.1.21(TOM01) 

And everything is good i have the MBEAN "java.lang:type=MemoryPool,name=PS Perm Gen" instead of "java.lang:type=MemoryPool,name=Perm Gen"

What's wrong with this host ;'( [192.168.1.20(TOM04)]

Comment: PS = parallel scavenge

I don't know why i have not the same on the two host but anyway... I want to have all my instance with PS XXXX so i just add in setenv.sh ( JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -XX:+UseParallelGC" )

Answer (score 1):

PS = parallel scavenge

I don't know why i have not the same on the two host but anyway... I want to have all my instance with PS XXXX so i just add in setenv.sh ( JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -XX:+UseParallelGC" )

Comment: My two systems have different amounts of RAM. I'm guessing that affects which option it chooses by default. This worked for forcing it to choose one.

Answer (score 1):

The 64-bit JVM defaults to the Parallel GC by default, whereas 32-bit JVM does not. That is why you see "PS Perm Gen" on one, and regular "Perm Gen" on the other. Most likely, one of them is using a 64-bit JRE/JDK and the other is using 32-bit (even if both machines are 64-bit)

You can of course specify GC options manually to force the same GC in both environments if you want...or, if they are both 64-bit... just verify you are using a 64-bit JVM in both environments. (or 32-bit in both environments, if memory is not an issue)

You can verify this by running "java -version" in both environments (assuming you are using the in PATH JRE/JDK and not a separate one specified by JAVA_HOME, which Tomcat might) and should see one say "64-bit Server VM" and the other will say "Client VM". At least, I can replicate your behavior in this way...

Comment: 192.168.1.20(TOM04):
setenv.sh > export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/default

/usr/java/default -> /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05

su - tomcat

-bash-4.1$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_05"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_05-b06)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.1-b03, mixed mode)

Comment: 192.168.1.21(TOM01):

setenv.sh > export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/default

/usr/java/default -> /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05

su - tomcat
-bash-4.1$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_05"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_05-b06)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.1-b03, mixed mode)

Sorry for the bad formating

Comment: generally JAVA_HOME has no bearing on what runs when you run "java" from the command line, but I believe Tomcat respects it. So getting that from the command line is not a good enough indicator. I see that you're looking at the MBeans in JConsole...look at the VM Summary tab, top left (2nd field) "Virtual Machine" will indicate version as well. In your case, verify the same value is in both. My guess is that one is using the 32-bit Client VM

Comment: all 64 bit: TOM04 http://img6.imageshack.us/img6/4509/screenshotfrom201305271.png